# Order by Xamarin request

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I am a  novice in Xamarin . I looking for a way to do a sqlite request order by , but It is not working.

I want to sort my listview by asc or desc when I click on the button

here is my button:

```
<Button Text="sort"  WidthRequest="40"  HeightRequest="40" Clicked="OnSort" />
```

here is my methode :

```
void OnSort(object sender, EventArgs args)
{

    var words = mywordsdatabase.SortWords();
    listWordsView.ItemsSource = words;
}
```

Here is my database method : 
//Sort Worder

```
public List<MyWords>  SortWords()
{
    var myword = (from word in conn.Table<MyWords>()

        orderby  word.ID descending

        select word );

    return myword.ToList();
}
```

Comment: You'll need to specify the symptoms of 'not working'

Comment: when I push on a button to sort , nothing happen

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What should be the difference between before and after? What should is the expected output? What is the occuring output?

Comment: when I clicked on the button I want to sort my list on descending or ascending but I cannot see how .

Comment: For the moment when I clicked on the button the list is sorted by descending , now what I want is when I clicked  again on the button the list is back to  ascending

Comment: you'll need a state variable that tracks which sort you should be using, and then either use the "descending" keyword in your sort expression or leave it out, depending on the current state.

Comment: Can you give me an example please ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort list just use LINQ.

**EDIT** Use a bool flag to check if you want to sort by ascending/descending order, something like this

```
public List<MyWords>  SortWords(bool sortAscending)
{
    var wordList = conn.Table<MyWords>();

    if(sortAscending){
        return wordList.OrderBy(w=>w.ID).ToList();
    }
    else{
        return wordList.OrderByDescending(w => w.ID).ToList();
    }
}
```

And to update your list view do this in your button click event

```
listWordsView.ItemsSource = null;
listWordsView.ItemsSource = mywordsdatabase.SortWords();
```

Comment: Thank but I when I order it by descending or Ascending when I clicked on the button

Comment: then just use this `wordList.OrderBy(w => w.ID).ToList();`

Comment: It is not working with : wordList.OrderBy(w => w.ID).ToList();  nothing Happen

Comment: I am looking for a way to sort my list by asc or desc  when I clicke on a button

Comment: Would you check if your ListView is not updating or your list is not sorting ? try to pass a dummy list to check if your `ListView` is updating or not.

Comment: I have tried it , if the list is already sort when I use wordList.OrderBy(w => w.ID).ToList(); nothing happen ofcourse but when I use return wordList.OrderByDescending(w => w.ID).ToList(); the list is sorted . At the moment I am looking for a State variable which will send something a boolea or a int then I will do both descending and asending when I click on the button